# how to install clover etl server [Apache Tomcat]

Tags: java, tomcat, clover, cloveretl

I am completely new to JAVA and Clover ETL

http://www.cloveretl.com/

I am trying to install the clover ETL Server to :

1. Use my custom extended components
2. use clover engine in a cluster computing environment

The steps I am following :
http://doc.cloveretl.com/documentation/UserGuide/index.jsp?topic=/com.cloveretl.server.docs/docs/installation-enterprise.html

In the above link it says :

**Installation of CloverETL Server

Download the web archive file (clover.war) containing CloverETL Server for Apache Tomcat.**

Question : Where exactly is this clover.war file 

I am unable to find it .

---

**UPDATE:** 
Also, I have a **cloverserver.bat** file in the **cloverETL.rel-4-1-0-M1\cloverETL\bin** folder on the engine that i downloaded from the clover website.

How can this file be utilized because i couldn't find any help doc on that

Answer (score 0):

CloverETL Server alone is not suitable to run in cluster-wide environment. I would suggest to use CloverETL Cluster that run transparently group of CloverETL Servers as if it was one entity. Alternatively, you might build your own cluster-wide Clover using CloverETL Open source engine that you can download from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cloveretl/files/cloveretl.engine/)

If your organization is thinking about trying CloverETL Cluster/Server then I would suggest to contact our sales department on `sales@cloveretl.com` to request an evaluation version.

The best way to get information about CloverETL and evaluation version is on [here](http://forum.cloveretl.com/) and `eval-support@cloveretl.com` as this forum is not checked regularly.

Comment: Okay, but is CloverETL Server (as you mentioned) downloadable and open to use and experiment?

Comment: also the source i downloaded from clover website has a **cloverserver.bat** in the directory "cloverETL.rel-4-1-0-M1\cloverETL\bin". how can it be utilised. i couldnt find any resource/doc on that.